# Visual Studio 2022 started using C++/CLI syntax when debugging a C# project

Tags: visual-studio-2022

My Visual Studio 2022 is suddenly displaying C# concepts on the VS GUI in a C++/CLI .

It is also displaying class names with a caret (^) character suffix, and showing "nullptr" for null objects instead of "null".

Any ideas on how to solve it?

Here is an example stack trace. Note how the "Language" column shows "C++".
[Call stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXtar.png)

I already re-install visual studio, reset settings.
We have almost 30 dev's in the company and I'm the only one with this problem

This is happening only in projects with the .NET framework

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Debugging information to "Portable"
In the project properties -> Build tab -> Advanced button. Under the 'Output' section. Then Rebuild the solution.

It worked for me...

Comment: It works also for me... Do you have any idea of what could cause this?

Comment: I can make some assumptions but I don't know for sure. Maybe they changed the format of the symbol file in the last update? Or maybe it is a bug? I don't remember changing anything that should affect this. Do you?

Comment: I don't think so, but this could be related
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS2022178C-The-identifier-is-not-defin/10520176

What I don't understand (if this is the problem) it's why only me have the problem. Some colleagues with the same version don't have the issue